# Cannot read repeating characters

Tags: java, string, loops, char

I'm writing a code to read a string and count sets of repeating

```
public int countRepeatedCharacters()
{
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < word.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i + 1)) // found a repetition
        {
            if ( word.charAt(i - 1) != word.charAt(i)) {

                c++;

            }
        }
    }     
    return c;
}
```

If I try the input
aabbcdaaaabb
I should have 4 sets of repeat decimals
aa | bb | aaaa | bb

and I know I'm not reading the first set aa because my index starts at 1. I tried fixing it around to read zero but then I tr to fix the entire loop to work with the change and I failed, is there any advice as to how to change my index or loop?

Comment: When u hit a repetition save the character so that next time u can check if its the same char. And start the loop from 0.

Comment: Ahh, I'll try that, I'm start to notice that I'm only rising the count every change in letters

Answer (score 1):

from what I understood from your question, you want to count number of repeating sets, then this should help.

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length()-1; i++){
    if (word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i + 1)){ // found a repetition
        if (i==0 || word.charAt(i - 1) != word.charAt(i)) {    
            c++;    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, for your second if statement you set index = 0? Didn't know I could do that!

Comment: @qvd i didnt set index, its a check to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBounds : (i-1) when i=0

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
public int countRepeatedCharacters(String word)
{
    int c = 0;
    Character last = null;
    bool counted = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        if (last != null && last.equals(word.charAt(i))) {  // same as previous characted
            if (!counted) {  // if not counted this character yet, count it
                c++;
                counted = true;
            }
        }
        else {      // new char, so update last and reset counted to false
            last = word.charAt(i);
            counted = false
        }
    }     
    return c;
}
```

Edit - counted aaaa as 4, fixed to count as 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this----

```
    public int countRepeatedCharacters()
{
    int c = 0,x=0;
    boolean charMatched=false;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        if(i==word.length()-1)
        {
            if (word.charAt(i-1) == word.charAt(i))
                 c++;
            break;
        }
        if (word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i + 1)) // found a repetition
        {

            charMatched=true;
            continue;
        }
        if(charMatched==true)
        c++;
        charMatched=false;          
    }     
    return c;
}
```

Comment: flag represent that either  two consucative  character matched or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method. It counts the sets of repeating charactors.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "aabbcdaaaabbc";
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length()-1; i++) {

        // found a repetition
        if (word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i + 1)) {
            int k = 0;
            while((i + k + 1) < word.length()) {
                if(word.charAt(i+k) == word.charAt(i + k + 1)) {
                    k++;
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            c++;
            i+=k-1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:-

```
public static void main(String str[]) {
    String word = "aabbcdaaaabbc";
    int c = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i + 1)) {
            c++;
        } else {
            System.out.println(word.charAt(i)+ " = " +c);
            c = 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(word.charAt(word.length()-1)+ " = " +c);
}
```

You can modify this as per your needs, by removing the `sysouts` and other stuffs.

Comment: Thank you very much, this wouldn't work for strings with no repeating letters though, but this helped!

Comment: It would! It'll give `1` as the repetition count. Try for a string say `test` & let me know if it works or not!

Answer (score 0):

Using length() -1 is causing you to not consider the last character in your calculations.
This is causing you to lose the last repetitive character.

Finally, I would have done this as follows:

```
 public static int countRepeatedCharacters(String word)
    {
        boolean withinRepeating = false;
        int c  = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < word.length(); i++)
        {

            if (!withinRepeating && (withinRepeating = word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i - 1)))
            c++;                        
            else
            withinRepeating = word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i - 1);
        }     
        return c;
    }
```